# Chrome function works only once

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I got this chrome function

```
var page_loaded = false;
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, info) {
    if (info.status === "complete") {
        page_loaded = true;
    }
});
```

Can someone explain why this function works only once when I refresh extension in URL *chrome://extensions/* when I refresh page this function doesn't work anymore until I refresh extension again... why?

**UPDATE**

This is how I know it doesn't work the alert goes once and after that silence...

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    if (page_loaded == true) {
       //Do stuff
    }
    else {
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

Comment: How would you know it works? It doesn't _do_ anything by itself, we don't know the rest of your extension's logic, and we don't know if you have `persistent` set for your background script.

Comment: It seems to me it's functioning correctly - after ANY tab finishes loading, the `alert` shouldn't work anymore as `page_loaded` is set to true and there's nothing to set it to `false` ever again.

Comment: @Xan thank you! I added another if to check if page is loading

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: @Xan Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments discussion, the problem was in extension's logic.

It used a boolean flag `page_loaded`, however there is only code to set it to `true` and no logic to reset it to `false`.

Adding setting it to `false` under appropriate conditions fixes the issue.

Note that you might want to track this state *per tab*.